# How can I use callback on Bootstrap Modal confirm?

Tags: jquery, callback, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and I need to return `true` if user clicks confirm.
At the moment I'm not able to use data attributes like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

I'm not to familiar with callbacks and I want to return `TRUE` when user clicks confirm. Is there a way I can achieve this? [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KyL5/3/).

**Put in context;**  I want to delete a record. If return `true`, then continue deletion.

```
$('#butt').click(function() {
    $('#content').portalDialogue({
        title : 'Hjelp',
        confirm: true,
        btnClose : 'Lukk',
        btnConfirm : 'OK',
        action: '#'
    });
});

(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.portalDialogue = function(option,callback) {
        var self   = this;
        var title   = option.title || 'Melding';
        var confirm   = option.confirm || false;
        var btnClose   = option.btnClose || 'Lukk';
        var btnConfirm   = option.btnConfirm || 'Ok';

        // Title
        $('.modal-title').text(title);
        // Close button
        $('.btnClose').html(btnClose);
        // Confirm button
        $('.btnConfirm').html(btnConfirm);
        // Dialog text
        $('.modal-body').html($(self).html());

        //IS confirm?
        if (confirm) {
            $('.btn.default').addClass('btn-default');
            $('.btn.confirm').removeClass('hidden').addClass('btn-primary').click(function(callback){
                return callback(true);                
            });
        } else {
            $('.btn.default').addClass('btn-primary');
            $('.btn.confirm').addClass('hidden');
        }

        // Open dialogue
        $('.default-modal').modal('show');
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that a callback function is an **object**. In this case, you pass it as the second parameter to the `portalDialogue` function. In my example, I'll use an anonymous function as a callback.

In the second section of the code, I bind another anonymous function on click, calling the callback function passed with arbitrary parameter (in this case, just `true`).

I'd change these lines:

```
$('#butt').click(function() {
    $('#content').portalDialogue({
        title : 'Hjelp',
        confirm: true,
        btnClose : 'Lukk',
        btnConfirm : 'OK',
        action: '#'
    }, function(ret){ // <-- our callback
        alert(ret); // or whatever code you need
    });
});

....

$('.btn.confirm').removeClass('hidden').addClass('btn-primary').click(function(){
    return callback(true);                
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9KyL5/4/

More on callbacks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/Callbacks

Comment: before the line
$('.btn.confirm').removeClass('hidden')...
i added
$('.btn.confirm').off('click');
to remove any previously added click events to prevent repeat execution of the callback when called more than once.